# Android studio ontouch

Tags: android-studio

//Necesito el metodo onTouchEvent para mostrar un Toast cuando el usuario //presione cualquier parte de la pantalla.

```
 public boolean onTouchEvent( MotionEvent event){

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Toast.makeText(this,"No puedes presionar la pantalla", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

Comment: Hola, esta pregunta no termina de quedar clara: ¿cuál es el problema que estás encontrando? ¿recibes algún error? Por favor, lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] y edita la pregunta o corre el riesgo de acabar cerrada. Además de añadir más detalles, también deberías mejorar el título (no es descriptivo del problema ahora mismo) y las etiquetas (el problema es con Java o con android, no con Android Studio que es el IDE utilizado para desarrollar).

Comment: Aparte, la función es `onTouchEvent` pero has escrito `onTochEvent` (sin la `u`), puede que el problema se deba a un simple fallo tipográfico.

Comment: no hay error, si no que tengo el metodo pero no me ejecuta la accion con el toast no se que haciendo mal. el onTouchEvent ya le agregue la U

Comment: Ok. Por favor, actualiza el código con lo que tengas ahora (para quitar el error tipográfico que puede despistar) y extiéndelo para añadir la parte del código donde se utilice/asocie el método.

Comment: ya esta. solo el de la u verdad?

Comment: Creo que sólo eso... la verdad es que no he trabajado en Java en bastante tiempo y no sé si hace falta algo más :-/

Comment: Pero ese evento se lo tendrás que asociar a algo. A un View al que le añades el listener. De forma que cuando pulse sobre ese elemento de tu interfaz, se ejecute ese onTouch. A qué control de tu ventana quieres asociar el evento?